# How can I add to a SortedArrayList using BinarySearch and Comparable?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, binary-search

I have been asked to write a `SortedArrayList` that extends `ArrayList` to add values to a `SortedArrayList` and sort them as they come in. I've been struggling with problem after problem. I can't figure out a good way to handle initial values without getting errors, but also maintain sorting my values as they come in, but still exiting the loop properly. It can't return anything and can't take an array as input. I'm only allowed to use what is there structure-wise.

I've tried changing the initial mid and high values. Changing how the values change based on which if/else is satisfied. I've completely rewritten this several times trying to come at it from a different direction, but still encounter the same issues.

```
package net.datastructures;
public class SortedArrayList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends ArrayList<E>{

    public SortedArrayList(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int i, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if(super.size()==0){
            super.add(i, e);
        }
        else{
            int low = 0;
            int high = super.size() - 1;
            while(low<=high){
                int mid = (low + high) / 2;
                E midVal = super.get(mid);
                if (e.compareTo(midVal) < 0) {
                    if(mid==0){
                        super.add(low, e);    
                    }
                    else{
                        super.add(mid - 1, e); 
                        low = mid + 1;
                    } 
                }   
                else if (e.compareTo(midVal) > 0) {
                    if(mid==0){
                        super.add(high, e);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                    super.add(mid + 1, e);
                    high = mid - 1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    super.add(mid, e);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Using another program, it should take any number of values added in, and sort them correctly as they are added.

Comment: Couple of quick thoughts : 1) by definition, your `add` should not take an `int i` (the element will go where it belongs).  2) Move all the `super.add` statements out of the `while` loop;  The job of the `while` loop is to set a variable (say `index`) to where the element should be inserted - so your `add` method should have a single `super.add(index, e)` that should be positioned after the `while` loop.

Comment: Also, put some log statements in the while loop, to output `low`, `high`, `mid` (and the values at those indexes) so you can see how the search is progressing.   Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow :)